# Constructor Inheritance: : Wrong argument count for constructor call

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, constructor, inheritance

In the following, why is the constructor of `C` not inherited by `CExt` so that it can be used by another extending contract `CExtChild`?

```
contract C {
    uint id;
    constructor(uint _id) {
        id = _id;
    }
}

contract CExt is C { }

/*
error[7927]: TypeError: Wrong argument count for constructor call: 1 arguments given but expected 0. Remove parentheses if you do not want to provide arguments here.
 --> src/CBaseExt.sol:18:23:
*/
contract CExtChild is CExt(1) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work like this:

```
contract CExt is C { 
  constructor(uint value) C(value){}
}

contract CExtChild is CExt(1) { }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `CExt`'s constructor has an empty function signature and cannot accept arguments. The constructor of `C` is inherited by `CExt`, however,`CExt` doesn't have its own constructor defined. [If](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#constructors) there is no constructor, the contract will assume the default constructor, which is equivalent to `constructor() {}`.

You should modify the `CExt` contract to accept the constructor argument and pass it to the base contract `C`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract C {
    uint id;
    constructor(uint _id) {
        id = _id;
    }
}

contract CExt is C {
    constructor(uint _id) C(_id) { }
}


contract CExtChild is CExt(1) {}
```